# Easily localized alternative to SQL Server Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, localization

We are running into the well-documented problems with localizing our SSRS reports.

Can anyone recommend an alternative?  Presume parity (or nearly so) with SSRS' functionality, though a great many of our reports will be simple grids or graphs, with some header/footer text.  We want a means by which we can easily identify localizable strings, store them in a database, translate them, and then generate the localized "report definition" at deployment time.  The Spanish see Spanish reports, the Italians see Italian reports, etc.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

There's a book called "Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Recipes" that has a few pages dedicated to how to localize SSRS reports. The only limitation is that parameter prompt text can still only show a single language (as it doesn't allow expressions); if you're accessing reports via a client though then it won't be an issue.

It involves creating a custom assembly in VS that has a main function that does the translation (using localization resource files, in much the same way you'd do it for an application).

Then you override the report's OnInit in custom code to initialise the custom assembly resource manager with the report name (so it knows which set of strings to look up, I suppose), and then instead of using "Name: " text in your report, you can use =Code.my_localizer.GetLocalText("Name")

Comment: could you elablorate how to localise parameter text on a .rdl that are consumed by ASP.NET ReportViewer. The reportViewer needs localisation.

Answer (score 0):

try to put some parameter on ssrs and create procedure like this:

```
--TEST
--DECLARE @language int
--SET @language = 2 --1 Italian  --2 Spain

--passing language parameter from ssrs report
IF (@language = 1)
    SELECT englishNameField1 as italianFieldName1, englishNameField2 as italianFieldName2, englishNameField3 as italianFieldName3
    FROM tableName
ELSE
    SELECT englishNameField1 as spanishNameField1, englishNameField2 as spanishNameField2, englishNameField3 as spanishNameField3
    FROM tableName  
WHERE parameterFromSSRS = @language
```

in report put parameter @language with some expression on UserID (Built-in Fields) to get language(localization)

Comment: I think you're describing how to pull localized data from the database.  That's not the problem.  I mean the free-standing text used in the report layout.  I don't have an image to link to but...imagine a report listing a person's sales.  At the top a label might say "Name:" and at runtime the person's name is inserted dynamically from the database.  But how do I localize the phrase "Name:"?  Or at the bottom of the report if it says "Page 1 of 5" in the footer, how do I localize "Page" and "of"?    Or to my original question, is there an alternative that makes it easier than SSRS does?

Comment: I really want to help
to me that the number of pages is correct, here's an example
put expression on textbox in footer:
="Страна  " & Globals!PageNumber & "  од  " & Globals!TotalPages
                                                                                            english: ="Page  " & Globals!PageNumber & "  of  " & Globals!TotalPages

Comment: now I'm a little investigating one possible solution is: put hidden paremeter on report adn give Default value:[&Language], then and then after that, make a localized two different tables and display allow the Tablix Visibility with "Hidden" expression: = IIF (Parameters! ReportParameter1.Value = "en-Latn-BA", true, false), and the second Tablix Visibility time: = IIF (Parameters! ReportParameter1.Value = "en-Latn-BA", false, true)